# Java main not running <terminated>

Tags: java

Just made a simple for loop, was playing around with some integers and was wondering why it keep saying  < terminated> and no print output?

```
public class CodingBat {


public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int x = 3; x == 0; x--){
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

When `x = 3` then `x == 0` is false so it never enters the loop. Most likely you intended.

```
for(int x = 3; x >= 0; x--) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of your terminating condition in your for-loop:

```
x == 0
```

`x` is not `0`, so it won't even run.

You probably wanted:

```
for(int x=3; x>0; x--)
```

Comment: Right, x ==0, is the terminating condition. So I thought it started as 3, went down in -1, so the expected print output is. 3,2,1.

Comment: @MichaelCowie The loop will check the terminating condition prior running (and before start of each iteration). So it starts with 3, checked that x is not 0, so it won't execute the codes in the loop.

Comment: @MichaelCowie If it solves your problem, you can accept the solution by clicking the hollow tick beside the answer which helps you best. You get 2 rep points in return. (You can only accept 1 solution per question)

Comment: @MichaelCowie You are correct until `Follow through x...` When it checks 3 == 0, fasle. The loop ends straight away. No more iterations.

Comment: ohh, I think I read it wrong. If I read it as while x >= 0, follow through the code. It's better. I see, thanks :D

Comment: Good to know you are clear now. Just remember, If terminating condition `is true -> run loop`. `is false -> exit loop`.